# How to combine two urls in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have declared two variable for url as below

```
    Url = vars.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
    url1 = vars.get("/questions");

    driver.get(Url + Url1);
```

When I am executing it, it is opening a web browser but there is no url address in the browser and nothing is happening. Could you please let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: First of all, what is `vars`? There's not enough code here to be able to determine an answer by simply looking at it. You should check to see if `Url` and `Url1` actually contain the data you expect, possibly by printing out their values to the console or something.

Comment: My suspicion is that `vars.get("http://stackoverflow.com");` and `vars.get("/questions");` aren't actually doing what you expect them to do, and are instead returning `null` or empty strings. If this is the case (and it may not be), then you're getting `Url + Url1` which would be null or empty.

Comment: yes Shtgun Ninja,that's what happening,they are returning null values.Can you please suggest something so i dont need need to use vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easiest to do if you put both urls like `Strings` as this:

```
Url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
url1 = "/questions";
```

And then you can combine both `Strings` with "`+`" simbol:

```
driver.get(Url + Url1);
```

But what it's exactly vars? Can you explain it please?

**EDIT:** .get method in Selenium Webdriver needs a String in their declaration to works properly. Look at this: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-

> Key methods are get(String), which is used to load a new web page, and the various methods similar to findElement(By), which is used to find WebElements.